# Last letter attached to stringByReplacingCharactersInRange

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch

I have a `UItextfield` that auto completes its value based on a pre defined string.  If  more than one word is in the first string `currentString`, the resulting display has the last char of `currentString` appended to it.

So in the example code

When typing `No`,  the `UITextField`s resulting text becomes `Note todayt` (last letter of second word appended to string)

```
 - (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range  replacementString:(NSString *)string {

NSString *currentString = [_txt.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];


 NSString *currentString = [_txt.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
if ([currentString isEqualToString:@"No t"]) {
    textField.text = @"Note today";
```

Is there a way I can avoid this behaviour?

I have tried

```
 if(_txt.text.length>1)
    {
       _txt.text =[textField.text substringToIndex:[textField.text length] - 1];

    }
```

and

```
if(_txt.text.length>1)
    {
        NSString *text2;

        NSString *currentString = textField.text;
        NSString *newString = [text2 substringToIndex:[text2 length]-1];
        textField.text=newString;
    }

    return NO;
}
return YES;

}
```

Comment: Would the down voter care to explain why? What is the point of SO if you cant ask questions.

Answer (score 2):

I'm willing to bet that you return YES, which causes the "t" to get typed.

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range  replacementString:(NSString *)string {
  NSString *currentString = [_txt.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];

  if ([currentString isEqualToString:@"No t"]) {
    textField.text = @"Note today";
    return NO;
  }

  return YES;
}
```

Comment: And I'm willing to believe that you can only win this bet ;)

Comment: Correct, im returning yes, your answer implies I should not be doing this?

Comment: @JSA986 The method is asking you "should I let the user type a T?". If you change the text and return YES, the text field lets the user type the T and you end up with an extra T.

Comment: @TC OK makes sense and I realise that im doing something wrong here but I cant return NO as i tried that,  what would your advice be as I dont know how to rectify this?

Answer (score 0):

Ok sorted this, I added an if statement to delete the extra character

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range  replacementString:(NSString *)string {

NSString *currentString = [_txt.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range  withString:string];


NSString *currentString = [_txt.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
if ([currentString isEqualToString:@"No t"]) {
textField.text = @"Note today";

  }


 if(_txt.text.length>=4)

  {
        NSString *text;

        text =[[textField text] stringByAppendingString:string];
        NSString *newString = [text substringToIndex:[text length]-1];

        textField.text=newString;


    return NO;

   }
   return YES;
}
```